# Spring MVC - why my GET manager method shows a javascript alert instead of redirecting?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having trouble trying to perform a redirect to a GET manager method that receives some POST parameters.

I'm using Spring 4.1.6 release with Java 1.7

My intent is to update the view with the new data I get from my database. Instead of a reloading, it just shows an alert with (I hope, but is partially encoded) the content of the view.

Performing some *System.out.print* I can see my GET method being called, and the parameters I sent on the POST request are there. Also, the database data is exactly what I want to show on the view.

Here are the two controller methods involved:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminUsuariosGet(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    Model model)
{
  Integer pagina;
  Integer itemsPorPagina;
  String ordenacion;
  String dirOrdenacion;

  if (model.asMap().get("pagina") == null)
  {
    pagina = 1;
    itemsPorPagina = 10;
    ordenacion = "idUsuario";
    dirOrdenacion = "asc";
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("model is not null");
    pagina = (Integer) model.asMap().get("pagina");
    itemsPorPagina = (Integer) model.asMap().get("itemsPorPagina");
    ordenacion = (String) model.asMap().get("ordenacion");
    dirOrdenacion = (String) model.asMap().get("dirOrdenacion");
  }

  Page<UsuariosEntity> objetoPagina = consultarUsuarios.obtenerPaginaUsuarios(
      pagina, itemsPorPagina, ordenacion, dirOrdenacion);

  List<UsuariosEntity> users = objetoPagina.getContent();

  System.out.println(users);

  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("adminUsuarios");
  mv.addObject("ultimaPagina", objetoPagina.getTotalPages());
  mv.addObject("users", users); // añadimos algo para usar en la vista
  mv.addObject("pagina", pagina);
  mv.addObject("itemsPorPagina", itemsPorPagina);
  mv.addObject("ordenacion", ordenacion);
  mv.addObject("dirOrdenacion", dirOrdenacion);

  return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adminUsuariosPost(
    @RequestParam(value = "pagina") Integer pagina,
    @RequestParam(value = "itemsPorPagina") Integer itemsPorPagina,
    @RequestParam(value = "ordenacion") String ordenacion,
    @RequestParam(value = "dirOrdenacion") String dirOrdenacion,
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs)
{
  redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("pagina", pagina);
  redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("itemsPorPagina", itemsPorPagina);
  redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("ordenacion", ordenacion);
  redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("dirOrdenacion", dirOrdenacion);

  System.out.println("Método adminUsuariosPOST");
  return "redirect:/admin/users/";
  //return new RedirectView("/admin/users", true);
}
```

And here my *AppConfig* class:

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan("com.concretepage") 
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig {  
    @Bean  
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {  
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();  
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");  
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);  
        return resolver;  
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something? I've read some blog posts about redirects in Spring and asked in some sites but I get no answer that can guide me. Thanks in advance.

Relevant lines of the view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                  onclick="updateView(${pagina - 1});">
                  <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>

function updateView(pagina)
{
  var select = document.getElementById('selectNumPaginas');
  var itemsPerPage = select.value;
  var sorting = '${sorting}';
  var sortingDirection = '${sortingDirection}';

  console.log('changing to updateView ' + pagina + "\nitemsPerPage = " + itemsPerPage);

  minAjax({
        url : "<c:url value="/admin/usuarios/"/>",//request URL
        type : "POST",//Request type GET/POST
        //Send Data in form of GET/POST
        data : {
          pagina: pagina,
          itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage,
          sorting: sorting,
          sortingDirection: sortingDirection
        },
        //CALLBACK FUNCTION with RESPONSE as argument
        success : function(data) {
          alert(data);
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for the View ?

Comment: How are you calling adminUsuariosPost() on the client?

Comment: @RobertMoskal Updated with the relevant information of the view cause the view is very long.

Comment: @javaguy Updated with the relevant information of the view cause the view is very long.

Comment: Well, your JavaScript sends an AJAX request, gets the response back and calls alert() to show the response. Why are you surprised that an alert is being shown? If you want he whole page to be refreshed, set the location of the page to the URL you want to redirect to after the POST instead.

Comment: Why are you using the same URL again ?

Comment: @JBNizet thanks. Was old code and I forgot that alert call on success. Yes, maybe the best solution is to use pure Javascript to redirect to the same page. Why didn't you answered? xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `return "redirect:/admin/users/";` in your `POST` method, you actually need to redirect to a different URL or directly return a `View` simply which could show the updated data (in the database).

Comment: My idea was to use the same path (URL) because there is the view I used to show the first page and I want to reutilize my code. Is just the same view but with more information. Why do I need another URL? I will try returning a View as you say, but that will be tomorrow because I have to run the code in my office. Thanks

Comment: where and how? I'm a Spring newbie (no one realized yet)